# Why is the System.Threading.Timer callback method only called once?

Tags: c#, timer

This is my first attempt to use timers in general and specifically here System.Threading.Timer and it is obvious to me that I miss some piece of understanding of the concept. The task I want to solve is the following:

Everyday we recieve multiple data sets from an external source that we compile into reports and distribute internally. The external data is scheduled at a certain time but this delivery is sometimes delayed. We want to distribute our reports as soon as possible every day, and hence we try to read and compile the reports in close connection to the scheduled delivery time. However, days when some or all data is delayed we want to keep looking for it until it is recieved, or, if to long time passes, report missing data.

Below I have, a much simplified, sample code that is intended to accomplish this behaviour. However when I run this the code excutes and ends with only one call to the timer callback method for each report.

What I expect this code to do: The main method should create two instances of the ReportTimer, one for each reportItem. These ReportTimers should have their own two timers that should call the GenerateReport method and try to compile a report. If no data is available the timer should re-schedule itself and try again in 5 seconds, after the second try (or rather when it enters the method for the third time) it should quit re-trying and end. If we instead call ReportTimer with the count parameter to 4 or higher it should eventually print the report message on the console and then exit.

What actually happens: The two ReportTimers are instantiated and the first call to GenerateReport is called and we get the message on the console that the reports are not ready yet. Then the execution ends and no more is written to the console.

My question is twofold: The first: why does this happen in this set-up? Secondly, is there another, more preferred way of accomplish what I am trying to do?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Reporter
{
    class Program
    {
            static void Main()
            {
                    List<string> reportItems = new List<string>() { "reportItem1", "reportItem2" };

                    foreach (string reportItem in reportItems)
                    {
                            ReportTimer rt = new ReportTimer(reportItem, 2);
                            Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
            }
    }

    public class ReportTimer
    {
            int _counter, _maxCount;
            int _timerIntervalInMilliSeconds = 5 * 1000;
            string _reportItem;
            Timer _timer;
            bool _noMoreRuns = false;
            DateTime _reportDateReadyAt = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(12); // For the purpose of this example let's assume the report data is available in 12 seconds from start

            public ReportTimer(string item, int countTo)
            {
                    _counter = 0;
                    _maxCount = countTo;
                    _reportItem = item;
                    _timer = new Timer(GenerateReport, null, 0, Timeout.Infinite); //Immediately start an attempt to generate a report. 
            }

            public void GenerateReport(object state)
            {
                    _counter++;

                    if (ReadyToReport(_reportItem))
                    {
                            Console.WriteLine("This is the report of {0}.", _reportItem);
                            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
                            Console.ReadKey();
                            _noMoreRuns = true;
                    }
                    else if (_counter <= _maxCount)
                            Console.WriteLine("Report of {0} is not ready yet - {1}", _reportItem, DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
                    else
                    {
                            Console.WriteLine("The report of {0} could not be generated", _reportItem);
                            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
                            Console.ReadKey();
                            _noMoreRuns = true;
                    }
                    if (_noMoreRuns)
                            _timer.Dispose();
                    else
                            _timer.Change(_timerIntervalInMilliSeconds, Timeout.Infinite);

                    return;
            }

            private bool ReadyToReport(string _reportItem)
            {
                    bool isReady = false;
                    if (DateTime.Now >= _reportDateReadyAt)
                            isReady = true;

                    return isReady;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, when `Main` exits, application starts to shutdown. Second, when you write like this, this is possible that `Timer` will be left without an existing root to point to it, so it can get garbage collected.

Comment: @Spo1ler any suggestions how I keep `Main` alive until the last `Timer` is closed?

Comment: Have a volatile counter that's initially set to number of Timers and is decremented every time the timer finishes. When the counter is at zero, just exit the application. You can use some of the kernel thread synchronization primitives like Mutex to avoid sleeping a thread while waiting for completion.

Comment: I'm not sure that that's a right way to go

Comment: I think what you really want is a [service with a timer](https://www.google.rs/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23+service+with+a+timer). It's very common to write a service that does something every N seconds.

Comment: @Spo1ler I added a static counter to the ReportTimer which is incremented on each creation and decremented on disposal of the timer. Checked for number af timers still alive and let `Main`exit first when this counter reached zero. This works so, I can use this for the time being. But since you raised some concerns if this is the right way to go, perhaps there are other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: @bokibeg one thing I did not mention in my question is that this program is meant to be called from a general purpose service that calls different application through out the day. But I will definitely consider your suggestion.